# Compile-time constant expression lost when passing literal string to nested template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question regarding using a literal string as a compile-time constant argument for templates. Consider the following demo:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
struct size_type {
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<int32_t N>
constexpr size_t get_size(const char(&str)[N]) {
    return (str[N - 1] == '\0' ? N - 1 : N);
}

template<int32_t N>
constexpr auto get_size_type(const char(&str)[N]) {
    return size_type<get_size(str)>();
}

int main() {
    auto size1 = size_type<get_size("hello")>::value;    // #1 This compiles fine
    auto size2 = get_size_type("hello");    // #2 This fails to compile

    std::cout << size1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << decltype(size2)::value << std::endl;
}
```

What's strange is that #1 proves that if "hello" is a compile-time literal string (thus constexpr), then the return value of get_size should also be constexpr. Logically, #2 should also compile, but in practice, it fails because the constexpr attribute of "hello" seems to be lost.

On MSVC 2022, I get the following error:

```
1>C:\Users\pippocao\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.cpp(19,27): error C2975: 'N': invalid template argument for 'size_type', expected compile-time constant expression
1>C:\Users\pippocao\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.cpp(5): message : see declaration of 'N'
1>C:\Users\pippocao\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.cpp(24): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'auto get_size_type<6>(const char (&)[6])' being compiled
```

Why is this the case?